# How to maintain the state of a page which contains controls even after postback in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with dropdowns and grid view control. User selects the drop downs and gridview gets populated. I am providing rating for each row in grid view. when user trys to rate the row, I need to redirect him to the login page.Once he logins he needs to be redirected back to the same page with all the dropdowns and grid populated.

To achieve this how to maintain the state and what is the best approach.
Please help me.Thank you

Comment: ur using webforms or mvc?

Comment: session is the best and reliable way to get this, unless user don't take much time to login otherwise session will expire.

Comment: @Neel give that he is using " grid view control" I would say he using web forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depends on size of grid and the number of users?
If the grid is small and there are not alot of users on the site you can store the Grids DataSource into Session object then check on pageload if the object exist then prepopulate the grid.  (also store the selected dropdown value and set it)

If the grid is large and/or you will have many users.
You could just store the dropdown list selected value in a cookie (or session) then on page load check if that cookie exist and if so set dropdown list and reload Grid data from database

Comment: you can just use session if thats easier.
Or use a cookie that ends with the session

Comment: My grid is not that much big. Is it good way to store datasource object into session?

Comment: Thats fine - I store a grid with over 1000 rows. For 30 concurrent users and it works smoothly

Answer (score 0):

You have different choices here.

1. Save datasource of gridview in Session state (Daveo suggestion)

   - Problem with this is that it expires and depending on the size of the table might have problems with memory resources
2. Redirect to login page with query string 
   a. Something like window.location="../loginpage.aspx?value1=''&value2=''" 
   b. Then on login button click check if value1 is not null redirect again to your page with something like  window.location="../userratingpage.aspx?value1=''&value2=''" 
   c. Populate gridview using the querystring values

Another suggestion would be is to have a sort of popup screen for the login rather than redirecting the page. You would no longer have problems retaining the state and it would look more interactive. Just like "login with facebook" functionality of other sites

Comment: For generating popup, i need to use modal popup? Please share me any stuff if u have about popups

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Modal pop up will give you more choices to customize instead of others.

Here is a sample of it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24924/Login-SignUp-Screen-Using-AJAX-ModalPopupExtender